# Will my EBP always be the same?

Tags: assembly

I have noticed that every time I load an executable into WinDBG (32-bit) when doing debug for homework assignments, my EBP always contains the same address (0x0018ff94).

Will this always be the same on this computer no matter what I load into WinDBG?

Are there any other registers that always default to the same contents?

Comment: No: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_howard/archive/2006/05/26/address-space-layout-randomization-in-windows-vista.aspx

Comment: I read the blog post. So every time I reboot, I will get a different EBP?

Comment: Even though you might be able to observe that the value is in fact the same throughout a session you should never rely on that fact because it is undocumented behavior and could change at any time.

Comment: Short answer: you got lucky :)

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: Well, in a 32-bit address-space, it's not really all that unlikely. *If* ASLR is even used.